# How did the trees deviate from God's command?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, hashkafah-philosophy, creation, parashat-bereishit, trees

In Bereshis 1:11 God commands  עֵץ פְּרִי עֹשֶׂה פְּרִי לְמִינוֹ however in the next pasuk where it happens we find וְעֵץ עֹשֶׂה-פְּרִי אֲשֶׁר זַרְעוֹ-בוֹ, לְמִינֵהוּ. This discrepancy is explained by Rashi

עץ פרי: שיהא טעם העץ כטעם הפרי, והיא לא עשתה כן, אלא (פסוק יב) ותוצא הארץ עץ עושה פרי, ולא העץ פרי, לפיכך כשנתקלל אדם על עונו נפקדה גם היא על עונה ונתקללה:

1. How can inanimate objects "choose" not to follow the will of their creator?
2. Why didn't they just do what God commanded?
3. If they really didn't do what God commanded how can the pasuk say:  וַיְהִי-כֵן or וַיַּרְא אֱלֹהִים, כִּי-טוֹב if that isn't true?

Comment: Something I've always found interesting: The only tree (that I know of) where we actually eat the tree itself is the palm tree. Specifically the [Heart of plam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_of_palm). The date palm (i.e. lulav tree) is not typically used for heart of palm (because it kills the tree), but it can be.

Comment: I had understood that this was a reflection of the sin of First Man. Every single one of the days of creation has flaws built into it, as you'll see if you go through the Rashis. They were all designed to reflect the possibility that Adam would corrupt the creation.

Answer (score 3):

[Ohr HaChaim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14261&st=&pgnum=191) asks this question, how can inanimate objects disregard a heavenly command, and they do not even have a evil inclination? Ohr HaChaim answers that the trees misunderstood Hashem's will thinking that Hashem meant two different types of trees. Ohr HaChaim finishes off saying that he will explain elsewhere why the trees got cursed if it was a misunderstanding.

Comment: I don't think that really answers the question it just kicks the can down the road - how can inanimate objects "misunderstand" God? It also doesn't explain why the pasuk says "it was so" when it wasn't. The Alshich also offers a similarly perplexing solution

Answer (score 0):

The angels were created on the second day as Rashi brings from the Medrush. Consider that the Nephilim mentioned in Genesis are said to have been fallen angels that wanted to come down to earth to serve God; despite God warning them it was a bad idea. This is relevant because the earth and the plants and trees are connected to the angelic forces which influence them. I imagine they had some involvement in these cosmic mishaps. See Rashi “let us make man”, in the beginning of Genesis which discusses the matter of why and in what manner the angels where involved in the creation of man.
[A discussion of the capacity of angels for “sin” with sources.](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1055341/jewish/Can-Angels-Sin.htm)